# How to list files in DCIM/Camera folder?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to get a list of all files in the `DCIM/Camera` directory on Android. I'm 100% certain that the files exists in this location because I can see them in Ubuntu's file explorer when I navigate to my connected Android's `DCIM/Camera` directory. However, my app isn't showing any files. Here is what I've tried:

```
val dcim = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Camera")

var files = File(dcim.toString())
files.walk().forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

//Nothing happens^

I've also tried this:

```
val dcim = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Camera")
if (dcim != null) {
    val pics = dcim.listFiles()
    if (pics != null) {
        for (pic in pics) {
            //Never gets here...
        }
    }
}
```

`val pics = dcim.listFiles()` is an empty array.

My manifest file has both:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Ubuntu can see the files and so can other apps on my phone:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your apps target API and android version of the device? Do note that `requestLegacyExternalStorage` is ignored on android 11 devices if your app is targeting API 30 or higher.

Comment: @Pawel my target API is set to `30` and my device is running Android 11.. Does that mean I need to remove `requestLegacyExternalStorage`?

Comment: Legacy external storage was only a temporary solution to give developers more time to migrate to scoped storage. Sadly you have to use that convoluted API now, `File` can only be used for managing your apps local directory. If it's a local project you can just request `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and keep using `File` API but it will make your app unsuitable for app store release.

Comment: @Pawel oh ok I see . I need to access the DCIM directory, what "convoluted API" are you referencing?

Comment: You use the wrong function. getExternalFilesDir() delivers a completely different path.. Have a look at dcim.getAbsolutePath() to see.  Just use getExternalStorageDirectory() and so on for the right path.

Comment: `Does that mean I need to remove requestLegacyExternalStorage?` No. Leave it in case your app should run on an Android 10 device.